# Onchange the category dropdown display the feature post and blog list

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have three functions.

1. The first one is displaying my categories dropdown from the custom post.
2. The second is displaying the latest post(I have added the checkbox in each post if the user checked that then that will display in the latest post)
3. And the third will display my all the post.

Below is the code I am using it.

```
//category dropdown
    function categoriesDropdown(){
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
    ) );
     $output='';
     $output.='<select>';
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $output.='<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>'; 
    }
        $output.='</select>';
        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'showCategoryList', 'categoriesDropdown');
    
    // Feature blog if check box selected.
    function latestBlogView( $atts ){
          $the_query =array(
          'post_type' => 'blog',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 3,
          'meta_key' => 'latestblog',
          'meta_value' => 1,
          'order'      => 'DESC'
        );
        
        $postData = '';
        // The Loop
         $featured = new WP_Query($the_query);
        $postData.='<div class="latestBlogsWrapper articlesWrapper"><ul>';
        if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();
            
        $postData.= '<li><div class="grid-item"><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">
        <div class="blogBoxwrapper"> 
        <img src="'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, "full").'"> 
        <div class="blogCatname"><h5>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h5></div>
        </div></div></a></li>'; 
        
        endwhile; else:
        $postData.="Please select the feature post check box";
    
        endif;
         $postData .= '</ul></div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
        return $postData; 
    }
    add_shortcode( 'latestblogs', 'latestBlogView');
    
    // Blog list
    function BlogView( $atts ){
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'blog',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 30, 
            'orderby' => 'title', 
            'order' => 'DESC', 
        );    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        $data ='';
        $data.='<div class="articlesWrapper"><ul>';
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            $tid = $loop->ID;
            $data.= ' 
              <li>
                 <a href="'.get_permalink($tid).'">
                      <div class="blogBoxwrapper">
                         <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($tid).'">
                            <div class="blogCatname">
                              <h5>'.get_the_title($id).'</h5>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                    </a>
            </li>'; 
        endwhile;  
        $data.='</ul>
        
        <div class="pt-5 text-center btnLoadmore"><a class="blogbtn blogbtnred loadMore" href="javascript:void(0);">Read More Blog Posts</a></div>
        </div>';
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        return $data; 
    }
    add_shortcode( 'blogandarticles', 'BlogView');
```

Now what I am doing is, When the user changes the category from the dropdown then I have to display the latest blog and blog list related to that category.

For example: on page load, I am displaying all the posts by default. Now I have a category called `Movie` in the dropdown. Once the user selects the Movie from the dropdown then I have to show the Movie related post in the latest blog and blog list.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: this you need to do with jquery ? Also does your blogs and post have `$category->name` to identify that particular post is of that category ?

Comment: @Swati, Yes, I have a category name to identify the post. I need to know how can I solve this issue? Do I need to use ajax to get the post a display?

Comment: No need to use ajax just on change of select get value of it and compare with your post and blog div where the category matched show that div else hide

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

On change dropdown, I have to display the post list and feature post. So I used ajax.

I used the below function outside of the onchange event because whenever the user refreshes the page it will call my ajax and display the output whatever the dropdown selected.

```
callAjax_forLatestblog();
callAjax_forBloglist();
```

I used two ajax calls because I have to show two things along with dynamic heading.

If notice here, I added below `if-condition` in both the function. it will check the value of dropdown if it's not empty then it will call this condition.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['keyword'])
         )
      );
    }


function categoriesDropdown(){
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
) );
 $output='';
 $output.='<select name="catDropdown" id="catDropdown"><option value="">Everything</option>';
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $output.='<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>'; 
}
    $output.='</select>';

$output.='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>     
(function($) {  // ready handler

callAjax_forLatestblog();// on page load call ajax to get the latest post
callAjax_forBloglist();// on page load call ajax to get the blog list

$("#catDropdown").change(function() {
    callAjax_forLatestblog();
    callAjax_forBloglist();
    });
    function callAjax_forLatestblog(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "latestBlogView", keyword: $("#catDropdown").val() },
        success: function(data) {
         $("#latestblogs").html(data);
        }
    });
    }
    function callAjax_forBloglist(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "blogList", keyword: $("#catDropdown").val() },
        success: function(data) {
         $("#blogList").html(data);
        }
    });
    }
    })(jQuery);</script>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'showCategoryList', 'categoriesDropdown');
```

Below code for the blog list

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_blogList', 'blogList');
add_action('wp_ajax_blogList', 'blogList');
function blogList( $atts ){
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'blog',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 30, 
        //'orderby' => 'title', 
        //'order' => 'ASC', 
    );  
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['keyword'])
         )
      );
    }
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    $data ='';
    $data.='<div class="articlesWrapper"><ul>';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $tid = $loop->ID;
        $data.= ' 
          <li>
             <a href="'.get_permalink($tid).'">
                  <div class="blogBoxwrapper">
                     <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($tid).'">
                        <div class="blogCatname">
                          <h5>'.get_the_title($id).'</h5>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                </a>
        </li>'; 
    endwhile;  
    $data.='</ul></div>';
    echo $data;
     wp_die(); // it will remove 0.
}
```

Below code for feature post

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_latestBlogView', 'latestBlogView');
add_action('wp_ajax_latestBlogView', 'latestBlogView');
function latestBlogView($atts){
     $the_query =array(
      'post_type' => 'blog',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'meta_key' => 'latestblog',
      'meta_value' => 1,
      'order'      => 'DESC'
    );
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])){
    $the_query['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['keyword'])
         )
      );
    }
    $postData = '';
    // The Loop
     $featured = new WP_Query($the_query);
    $postData.='<div class="latestBlogsWrapper articlesWrapper"><ul>';
    if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();
    $postData.= '<li><div class="grid-item"><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">
    <div class="blogBoxwrapper"> 
    <img src="'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, "full").'"> 
    <div class="blogCatname"><h5>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h5></div>
    </div></a></div></li>'; 
    
    endwhile; else:
    $postData.="Please select the feature post check box";

    endif;
     $postData .= '</ul></div>';
    echo $postData;
     wp_die(); // it will remove 0.
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="blogList"></div>
<div id="latestblogs"></div>
```