# How to call the php function from the jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am displaying the category dropdown on my page and onChange event I have to call `latestBlogView()` function.

My all the codes are in function.php page.

1. Do I need to use AJAX?
2. Is it possible to do without AJAX?

I have to call this function

```
function latestBlogView($atts){
    var_dump($atts);
    $postData=$atts; // this code is for testing i have to use WP_Query here
    return $postData; 
}
add_shortcode( 'latestblogs', 'latestBlogView');
```

Displaying the dropdonw on my page

```
function categoriesDropdown(){
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
) );
 $output='';
 $output.='<select name="catDropdown" id="catDropdown">';
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $output.='<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>'; 
}
    $output.='</select>';
    $output.='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>(function($){$("#catDropdown").change(function() {
    var value=$("#catDropdown").val();
    latestBlogView(value); // calling function here
    });
    })(jQuery)</script>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'showCategoryList', 'categoriesDropdown');
```

Comment: Yes you would need ajax since you need to listen for an event when an option is selected - I am preparing an answer for you. Also what would you do when `latestBlogView` is being called when you select an option ? Are you adding all these `shortcodes` on one page.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Actually on page load I have to run this function latestBlogView() but when the user selects from the dropdown then I have to pass the value to this function and get the output and display.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Two days ago I ask one question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042866/onchange-the-category-dropdown-display-the-feature-post-and-blog-list


So I have to solve that. This is a small part of my question. You will get my whole code there

Comment: *but when the user selects from the dropdown then I have to pass the value to this function and get the output and display* - this is very confusing and that NOT how shortcode will work. For example: if you have `categoriesDropdown` shortcode on a page and then user select an option ajax will be called on this function `latestBlogView` - you will not see the updated data on the same page. a shortcode is a static thing which does not gets updated when you can call it. shortcode runs on a page. Does this make sense ?

Comment: ...you have return `$postData` from your `latestBlogView` and get it via `ajax` and then display on that same page where the user selected the option (if thats what your goal is!!!). Doing this `add_shortcode( 'latestblogs', 'latestBlogView');` will not work

Comment: Just notice in the reference link. By default, it's displaying all the data but when you change it then it's also changing the post data according to the category. I know this is a big task. So I am working on the small part to achieve this.

Comment: Yes the answer you posted is what i was going to post and i said the same thing in my comments that you need to display data via ajax success return `$("#latestblogs").html(data);` which are already doing it - **that is the best and correct way to do it**. So this question is resolved now i guess.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried and from my send and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using ajax and it's working. I don't know it's the best way or not but it's solved my issue.

I was using the `jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js` so I change it because I was getting the error in the console `$.ajax is not a function`.

I tried below ajax code

```
$output.='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>     
(function($) {  // ready handler
$("#catDropdown").change(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "latestBlogView", keyword: $("#catDropdown").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#latestblogs").html(data);
        }
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);</script>';
```

This is my function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_latestBlogView', 'latestBlogView');
add_action('wp_ajax_latestBlogView', 'latestBlogView');

function latestBlogView($atts){
echo "hello"; // if you want to display the variable output on screen then use return $postData; 
}
```